# OpenGL deferred rendering: point light implementation

Tags: c#, opengl, glsl, opentk, deferred-rendering

I'm trying to write a deferred renderer using C# and OpenGL (with OpenTK).

But don't understand how should I implement the normal calculation for a point light.

The point light fragment shader:

```
    vec2 texCoord = gl_FragCoord.xy / ScreenSize;

    vec3 pixelPos = texture2D(PositionBuffer,texCoord).xyz;
    vec3 pixelNormal = normalize(texture2D(NormalBuffer, texCoord).xyz);
    vec3 diffuseColor = texture2D(ColorBuffer, texCoord).xyz;

    vec3 toLight = LightCenter - pixelPos;

    float attenuation = clamp(1.0 - length(toLight)/LightRadius,0.0,1.0); 

    toLight = normalize(toLight);

    float nDotL = max(dot(pixelNormal, toLight),0.0);

    vec3 diffuseLight = diffuseColor * nDotL;

    LightMap = LightIntensity * attenuation * vec4(diffuseLight,1.0);
```

Result:
[image: The result]

It looks fine. But the light is on a 10*10 flat surface, and the radius of the light is 5, so the light should almost cover the surface.

I understand the problem, I just don't know how to fix it...

[image: Normal problem]

nDotL of further pixels will be smaller, which leads to this "artifact".

If I remove the "* nDotL" part the light looks like this:

[image]

In this case the range is fine, but the bottom of the floor is lit too...

I would be grateful if somebody could tell me how to fix this.

[Also the source code is here if it's needed.](https://github.com/robot9706/OpenGLDeferredRendering)

Comment: The attenuation terms looks somehow wrong to me. Shouldn't this in general be 1/length(toLight)? What you do at the moment is a linear fadeout between 0 and LightRadius.

Comment: Using "float attenuation = clamp(1.0 / length(toLight),0.0,1.0);" it looks better, but something is still wrong because I can see the edge of the light sphere. http://i.imgur.com/Vzlyj1s.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vec3 distance = toLight * (1.0 / LightRadius);
float attenuation = clamp(1 - dot(distance, distance), 0, 1);
attenuation = attenuation * attenuation;
```

Using this "formula" it looks like it's working as it should.

Answer (score 1):

It is normal that your lightning gets darkers when you combine Decay + Diffuse. 
As they are not 1.0 (but some value between 0.0,1.0) if you multiply both you get a darker result. You should increase the strength of the light. You can do

```
lightStrength / (ConstantDecay + distance*LinearDecay + distance*distance*CuadraticDecay).
```

It would give you a softer decay and allow you to increase the light effect to enlight more radius.

Comment: also, you are using screencoordinates on your texturecoordinates, I assume it is on purpose.

Comment: I'm using screen coordinates, because I'm using RT-s to render stuff. Anyway, thanks for the answer, I'll try it.

Comment: yeah, I was wondering it could be raytracing, but there were no Camera ray calculation , so I was mislead. You seem to be using the pixel distance from a 3d point light. You are using screen coordinates for the light, instead of raycasted light position. 
vec3 toLight = LightCenter - pixelPos;
You need to get the 3D position of the raycast collision.

Comment: EDIT: oh, now I see. You saved the distance data in the texture?

Comment: Yes exactly, Sorry I forgot to mention how the textures work and what they store :/

Comment: The light now looks better, but I don't understand what the values of "ConstantDecay ", "LinearDecay " and "CuadraticDecay", because I played them a little, but I can see the "edge" of the light. So it doesn't smooth out, it just ends.

Comment: the decay is just for smoothing the "light edge". Wich values do you use? I use (1.0,0.4,0.2). The ConstantDecay is used to inverse the calculation (but you can tweek it) the Linear is the distance depending decay and the Cuadratic is the "softeness" of the edge as it falls in curve.

Comment: If I use the values you gave I get this: http://i.imgur.com/1FOQZIG.png Also I used 1.0, 0.5, 0.1

Comment: seems better to me, are you satisfied?

Comment: Look closer, the edges of the light spheres are visible: http://i.imgur.com/9sAD1v5.png